# RabbitMQ's receiveAndConvert for clustered environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have this method implemented in a SpringBoot application

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void pullMessage() {
    MessageDTO message = null;

    try {
        message = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(properties.getQueueName(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<MessageDTO>() {});
    // more code here...


}
```

every 5 seconds I'm pulling a message from RabbitMQ and processing something with it. The application is running on Kubernetes and right now I have to duplicate the POD. In this scenario, could the two pods pull the same message?

Comment: Why do you this active polling? Just subscribe the topic and you need no scheduler.

Comment: And for your question: If subscribed, you can can control that a message is send to all subscribers vor just to one. Quality of service https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service

Comment: @akop I don't want to pull a message right when they arrive, I wanted to control and pull one message at a time every 5 seconds. Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: Why do you want to pull a message only all 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the queue is the same for all the instances, then no: only one consumer takes a message from a queue. That's fundamental purpose of the queue pattern at all.

See AMQP docs for publish-subscribe patterns: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html

Answer (score 0):

No only a single instance will process the message at one time, the whole purpose of having multiple consumers is not to have any downtime for the application!

Refer the official documentation of RabbitMQ for more clarification!
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html